# Where to place CSS3 transition

Tags: css, transition

Maybe this is a real silly question but I just can't stand not to know the answer so here I go:

A simple background change CSS3 transition can be placed on the element itself and also on the :hover state of this element and it both works! But: what is best practice?

Example:

```
.example {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.example:hover{
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  transition: all 2s ease-in;
}
```

this works as well:

```
.example {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 2s ease-in;
}

.example:hover{
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

Can somebody tell me why this is? And what is best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second scenario, you will have transition on all events. For example, you might have another CSS selector on `focus`, then that change will get the transition effects as well and take place over 2 seconds.

In the first scenario, transition is only applied to `hover` event.

Choose one depending on what you want to achieve.